# "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9001: connect: connection refused"

Tags: go, grpc

In golang I am trying to implement GRPC but getting this error. Everything else looks fine.

Here is the code snippet.

```
type EventServiceClient struct {
Client proto.EventServiceClient
Conn   *grpc.ClientConn
}

func InitEventServiceClient(addr int) (msc EventServiceClient, err error) {

conn, err := grpc.Dial("localhost:9001", grpc.WithInsecure())
if err != nil {
    return
}

client := proto.NewEventServiceClient(conn)
msc = EventServiceClient{
    Conn:   conn,
    Client: client,
}

return
}
```

Error-

rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9001: connect: connection refused"

Comment: make sure you can ping the host , also firewall is not blocking

Comment: not able to ping host but firewall looks good not any issue with it.

Comment: Please provide more information on the gRPC Server you are attempting to connect to (e.g. how have you verified that it's running, OS/environment info (docker?), can you connect with [gRPCurl](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl) or a similar tool).

Answer (score -1):

localhost may be ip6 (::1) - try 127.0.0.1:9001 or 0.0.0.0:9001 for all ip

Comment: No the localhost is ip4 for all ip